# Center absolute positioned element on left edge of container

Tags: css, position, centering

I need to center an image on the left (and another on the right) edge of an absolute positioned div i.e. the middle of the image lines up with the left edge of the container. The sizes of the image and container are fluid.

The images have to be absolutely positioned because there are a few of them that need to overlap. The solution has to be supported in IE8. I am free to add more containing elements, but would prefer to not do so if not absolutely necessary.

I could do this with javascript, but would really prefer a pure css solution.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve and what the code would look like: http://jsbin.com/yupuy/1/edit?html,css,output

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "center". The description is a bit vague. Anyhow, it sounds easy to do for modern browsers, but older ones would miss out. (Not many use IE8 any more, and they deserve a plainer layout, IMHO.)

Comment: My example shows clearly what I want. The first image is what I need, but using absolute positioning

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "center", but it sounds like you want something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/eexbohsx/1/

**CSS**

```
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Example" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the center the image in the container. I want the center of the image to line up with the left edge of the container

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you rightly, this is how you can do it for modern browsers: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/tJHjk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate(50%, 0);
  -ms-transform:translate(50%, 0);
  -o-transform:translate(50%, 0);
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img class="left" src="http://placehold.it/450x100" alt="">
    <img class="right" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could serve up some conditional JS for outdated browsers if it's really important to you.

Comment: So let me get this straight, a percentual value passed to translate refers to the width (or height) of the ELEMENT and not its parent? That's neat.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works, and it's brilliant for centering elements or unknown width and height.